# Rails - absolute URL for images in assets path for heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am having images under `app/assets/images/admin` directory.

In development I've used something like this to get the URL

```
"#{root_url}assets/admin/filename.jpg"
```

But its not working on Heroku.

So what is the best way to reference images under assets folder on Heroku?

Answer (score 3):

> reference images under assets folder

If you're using [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag), you'll be able to call the relative path regardless of whether you're in `production` or `development`:

```
<%= image_tag "admin/filename.jpg" %>
```

--

If you're calling the image in your *CSS*, you'll need to use [`asset-path` or `asset-url`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
.header {
   background: asset-url("admin/filename.png");
}
```

---

The problem you have is to do with [asset fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark).

When you *precompile* your assets (which is required in Heroku), all the `images`, `css`, `javascript` etc is put into the `public/assets` folder. More importantly, each file is *fingerprinted* (has some numbers appended to it):

```
global-908e25f4bf641868d8683022a5b62f54.css
```

Thus, calling `#{root_url}assets/admin/filename.jpg` will result in a **404** when you're in "production", because **the file will not exist**.

You need to use one of the path helpers (above) to make sure Rails can pick out the correct file, regardless of which environment you're using.

Answer (score 2):

use `image_tag('admin/filename.jpg')` to get the html with the part to the picture:

```
development# => <img alt="Rails" src="http://yourhost/assets/admin/filename.jpg" />
production# => <img alt="Rails" src="http://yourhost/assets/admin/filename-5643564625453543.jpg" />
```

use `image_path("admin/filename.jpg")` to get the path like this:

```
development# => "/assets/admin/filename.jpg"
production# => "/assets/admin/filename-5643564625453543.jpg"
```

use `image_url("admin/filename.jpg")` to get the full url like this:

```
development# => "http://yourhost/assets/admin/filename.jpg"
production# => "http://yourhost/assets/admin/filename-5643564625453543.jpg"
```

You can get more information on

[The Assets Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

[Asset URL Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html)

Comment: did you mean `image_url`?

Comment: No i mean image_url. How will you use it? To show the picture in your rails application?

Comment: @Swards i've updated it. I hope it is now more clearly.

Comment: @dthal Hey thanks man. But even if i try to access the image file with `http://myhost.com/assets/admin/filename.jpg`  i am getting **page doesn't exist** error.

Comment: @Swards Hi Swards. If i try to access the image file with `http://myhost.com/assets/admin/filename.jpg`  i am getting **page doesn't exist** error in heroku. Any help?

Comment: @PraveenKJ Did you use production or development mode?

Comment: is this the code?  `image_url('admin/filename.jpg')`

Comment: @dthal The same code works well in development say `http://localhost:3000-/assets/admin/filename.jpg ` But not in production (heroku)

Comment: @Swards I tried hitting the url directly before writing code. It works for local. But heroku says **The page you were looking for doesn't exist.** error

Comment: @PraveenKJ You must use for production the command `RAILS_ENV=production rake assests:precompile` to precompile the assets. The precompile will compress your pictures, add a random number and safe it to the public folder. With image_url in production you will get something like:
# => "http://yourhost/assets/admin/filename-456455724544534567454.jpg".

Comment: @dthal Thanks man. I think i have to read some documentation about assets pipeline. Appreciate your help though.